# I can't send notification using pusher in localhost laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I created a new `pusher` by composer And I checked it out in `pusher.com` in `debug console` and it works fine in my application But when I use it in my application it shows
`cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api-ap2.pusher.com/apps/1599154/events?auth_key=MyAuthKey&auth_timestamp=1683883232&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=52d281cb8c2ebbf275d55cd9e56fac72&auth_signature=33e9dfa92fef57f900b599047882f506cc419aed5b91cd631d4a4fb9d7e202b7`

I also downloaded `cacert.pem` and it to `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.2.0` And also changed `php.ini` the line `curl.cainfo ="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.2.0\cacert.pem"`.
Here is my view file

> 

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Pusher Test</title>
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/7.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>

    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('My_Pusher-Key', {
        cluster: 'ap2'
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
   </script>
   </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Pusher Test</h1>
  <p>
    Try publishing an event to channel <code>my-channel</code>
     with event name <code>my-event</code>.
  </p>
</body>
```

And here is `MyEvent` in `app/Events/MyEvent`

> 

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MyEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */

 public $message;

 public function __construct($message)
 {
     $this->message = $message;
 }

 public function broadcastOn()
 {
     return ['my-channel'];
 }

 public function broadcastAs()
 {
     return 'my-event';
 }

 }
```

And here is my routes.
I used `/notif` route to show pages for `showing notification` And `/notifTest` for `sending new notification` .
`/notif` works fine And i also tested it on `pusher.com` And works fine.
But when i load `/notiftest` I got `curl error`.

> 

```
Route::get('/notif',function(){
   return view('notif');
 });

 Route::get('notifTest', function () {

 event(new App\Events\MyEvent('Someone'));

 return "Event has been sent!";

});
```

Hope anyone help me.
Thanks.